# Define new ControlTemplate keeping the original events

Tags: wpf, controltemplate, color-picker

I want to use the ExtendedWPFToolkits's ColorPicker but with a custom ButtonStyle.
I can create a new look overriding the Template property of the item but the original templates click event is missing.

I want to keep it, but how?

```
<Controls:ColorPicker >
    <Controls:ColorPicker.ButtonStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Button Content="ColorPicker"></Button>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Controls:ColorPicker.ButtonStyle>
</Controls:ColorPicker>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is not valid. You are putting a `Button` in the ControlTemplate of a `ToggleButton`, so basically a button in a button.

You'd need to do something like:

```
<Controls:ColorPicker >
    <Controls:ColorPicker.ButtonStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border Background="Transparent">
                            <TextBlock Text="ColorPicker" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Controls:ColorPicker.ButtonStyle>
</Controls:ColorPicker>
```

I added a transparent `Border` so the button will be able to receive mouse events for areas not covered by the text.